# How to handle and search against huge array of data in Google environment?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-datastore

I am in the process of developing a Google App Engine application where users can read (and edit but it's not important atm) an address book. More specifically the Google Apps Directory address book.

Reading per se is not an issue since Google provides Directory API which I am familiar with. The problem is that my address book has thousands of entries and I need (almost) 0ms performance when searching. Also, I must be able to make a full text search on the address book. In the best scenario users want the entire data to be loaded at once.

Basically I come up with a couple of solutions.

1) Load the entire database in an Angular JS array on page load and then use ng-model to search. Performance are not good at all, meaning that sometimes the tab crashes or takes seconds to load results. It may be related to the fact that I am using angular-datatable to organize results but it's unlikely.

2) Use Google Datastore to make a replica of the address book but then I am stuck with the NO SQL schema. I heard Big Query can help but I've never used it, can I make full text search?

3) Use Google Cloud SQL but performance are not as fast as I'd like them to be.

4) Directly query the Google address book but from the [reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users) the only operators allowed are '=' and ':' and performance are not reliable. Not to mention along the address book I must read Shared Contacts as well.

5) ???

Do you have any suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: Datastore should give you good performance if you can be sure to replicate any Directory updates to Datastore.  However, you'd still need to index all sorts of substrings if you're looking for some kind of typeahead/autocomplete behaviour and you could easily end up with a lot of indexes depending on what fields you want searchable. Have you looked at the [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/)?  BigQuery uses an append-only model (e.g. for log analytics) so doesn't seem to fit your use case.

Comment: You should consider using the Search API - available for app engine applications. It's a "full text" document storage solution.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/  What language are you planning to work in?